# Django jinja2 template, extends another template. Django renders base template without jinja2

Tags: django, django-templates, jinja2

I'm using jinja2 to render a template in django:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2",
        "DIRS": [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates/jinja2/")],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {"environment": "management.jinja2_conf.environment"},
    },
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ]
        },
    },
]
```

The initial template is in `myproject/foo/templates/jinja2/...`. Jinja seems to find this fine. This template extends a base template, which is in `myproject/templates/jinja2/...`. This one cannot be found. Strangely, according to the template loader post-mortem, when django searches for the base template, it *does not* use jinja2 - it just uses the usual django backend. I have no idea why this is...

Post mortem:

```
Template loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/foo/.pyenv/versions/management/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/base_email.plain (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/foo/.pyenv/versions/management/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/base_email.plain (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/foo/.pyenv/versions/management/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/templates/base_email.plain (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/foo/work/sva/management/users/templates/base_email.plain (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/foo/work/sva/management/utils/templates/base_email.plain (Source does not exist)
```

Comment: Please show the actual post-mortem.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Done, but clearly no mention of jinja2